# C# ASP.Net + CR 13 - Parameter Values missing

Tags: asp.net, parameters, crystal-reports, report

I have a project consisting of a asp.net webpage generating report of total usage per day of a pertucular item.
the code worked in CR 9 with VS 2008 but since i converted it to CR 13 with VS 2010 the report is throwing error as "Parameter values missing" whenever i add a parameter to the report.
the parameter is in subreport.
the report is visible correctly without parameters.
[dt2 has records and i have filled it above the mentioned code]
i am only trying it for saturday first
the code i wrote is show below-

```
crReport cr = new crReport();
cr.SetDatabaseLogon(gf.databaseUsername, gf.databasePass);
((ReportDocument)cr.Subreports["MenuReport"]).SetDataSource(dt2);
#region Parameter gathering
ParameterValues paramQuantity = new ParameterValues();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dt2.Rows[i]["menuItemFK"] = jobBll.GetDataInfo("M_MenuItems", "id", dt.Rows[i]["menuItemFK"].ToString(), "menuItemName", true);
    string menuItemFK = dt.Rows[i]["menuItemFK"].ToString();
    string reportDate = dt.Rows[i]["reportDate"].ToString();
    DataTable dtQuntity = new DataTable();
    dtQuntity = jobBll.GetMenuItemDayUsage(menuItemFK, reportFrom, reportTo, "Saturday", true);
    ParameterDiscreteValue parameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    if (dtQuntity.Rows[0][0].ToString() != "")
        parameterDiscreteValue.Value = dtQuntity.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    else
        parameterDiscreteValue.Value = "0";
    paramQuantity.Add(parameterDiscreteValue);
}
#endregion
//cr.SetParameterValue("Sunday Quantity", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
//cr.SetParameterValue("Monday Quantity", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
//cr.SetParameterValue("Tuesday Quantity", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
//cr.SetParameterValue("Wednesday Quantity", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
//cr.SetParameterValue("Thursday Quantity", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
//cr.SetParameterValue("Friday Quantity", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
cr.SetParameterValue("saturdayQuantity", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
crvReport.ReportSource = cr;     
crvReport.RefreshReport();
```

Please help me as soon as possible.
waiting for replies.
thanks.

Comment: Which line is giving error? Please specify.

Comment: there is no error.
after completing this code the report shows "Parameter values missing", while i get all the parameters for all the records.

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally I go it working.
I declared 'cr' as 'ReportDocument' object instead or 'crReport.rpt' object also commented the cr.RefreshReport();, which was clearing out the parameter values.
now its working correctly.
to display individual parameter values for records i wrote 'display string' formula for the parameter as -

```
StringVar Array Input:={?saturdayQuantity};
Input[RecordNumber];
```

and the C# code now looks as follows-

```
ReportDocument cr = new ReportDocument();//
string reportPath = Server.MapPath("crReport.rpt");//
cr.Load(reportPath);//

((TextObject)cr.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["reportFrom"]).Text = reportFrom;
((TextObject)cr.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["reportTo"]).Text = reportTo;
cr.SetDatabaseLogon(gf.databaseUsername, gf.databasePass);

#region Parameter gathering
ParameterValues paramQuantity = new ParameterValues();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dt2.Rows[i]["menuItemFK"] = jobBll.GetDataInfo("M_MenuItems", "id", dt.Rows[i]["menuItemFK"].ToString(), "menuItemName", true);


        //GET OPENING & CLOSING STOCK TOTAL & ASSIGN BELOW
        string menuItemFK = dt.Rows[i]["menuItemFK"].ToString();
        string reportDate = dt.Rows[i]["reportDate"].ToString();

        DataTable dtQuntity = new DataTable();
        dtQuntity = jobBll.GetMenuItemDayUsage(menuItemFK, reportFrom, reportTo, "Saturday", true);

        ParameterDiscreteValue parameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        if (dtQuntity.Rows[0][0].ToString() != "")
            parameterDiscreteValue.Value = dtQuntity.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        else
            parameterDiscreteValue.Value = "0";

        paramQuantity.Add(parameterDiscreteValue);

    }

    cr.Subreports["MenuReport"].SetDataSource(dt2);

    ////cr.SetParameterValue("Sunday Quantity", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
    ////cr.SetParameterValue("Monday Quantity", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
    ////cr.SetParameterValue("Tuesday Quantity", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
    ////cr.SetParameterValue("Wednesday Quantity", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
    ////cr.SetParameterValue("Thursday Quantity", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
    ////cr.SetParameterValue("Friday Quantity", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
    cr.SetParameterValue("saturdayQuantity", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");

    ////cr.SetParameterValue("Sunday Rate", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
    ////cr.SetParameterValue("Monday Rate", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
    ////cr.SetParameterValue("Tuesday Rate", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
    ////cr.SetParameterValue("Wednesday Rate", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
    ////cr.SetParameterValue("Thursday Rate", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
    ////cr.SetParameterValue("Friday Rate", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
    ////cr.SetParameterValue("Saturday Rate", paramQuantity, "MenuReport");
    #endregion


    crvReport.ReportSource = cr;
    //crvReport.RefreshReport();//
```

**I have marked the edited code with // at end of line.**